# Huntington Motors

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

So i am doing a little advance exercise in VB.NET and i am a little froze to what i am doing. The task is "Each salesperson at Huntington Motors is assigned an ID number that consists of four characters. The first character is either the number 1 or the number 2. A 1 indicates that the salesperson sells new cars, and a 2 indicates that the salesperson sells used cars. The middle two characters are the salesperson’s initials, and the last character is either the letter F or the letter P. The letter F indicates that the salesperson is a full-time employee. The letter P indicates that he or she is a part-time employee... The application should allow the sales manager to enter the ID and number of cars sold for as many salespeople as needed. The application should calculate and display the total number of cars sold by each of the following four categories of employees: full-time employees, part-time employees, employees selling new cars, and employees selling used cars." 
[this is my interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyWuW.jpg)
This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
btnCalculate.Click
    'variables
    Dim strInput As String = ""
    Dim strOutput As String = ""
    Dim intFullTime As Integer = 0
    Dim intPartTime As Integer = 0
    Dim intNewCar As Integer = 0
    Dim intUseCar As Integer = 0
    Dim intNumSold As Integer
    strInput = txtId.Text
    ' changes the id number case to upper
    strInput = txtId.Text.ToUpper()
    ' sets the focus
      txtId.Focus()

   Integer.TryParse(txtNumberSold.Text, intNumSold)
    If strInput Like "[12][A-Z][A-Z][FP]" Then
        If strInput.Substring(0) = "1" Then
            intNewCar = intNewCar + intNumSold
            txtNewCar.Text = intNewCar.ToString
        Else
            intUseCar = intUseCar + intNumSold
            txtUsedCar.Text = intUseCar.ToString
        End If

        If strInput.Substring(3) = "F" Then
            intFullTime = intFullTime + intNumSold
            txtFullTime.Text = intFullTime.ToString
        Else
            intPartTime = intPartTime + intNumSold
            txtPartTime.Text = intPartTime.ToString
        End If
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Now my problem is, when is enter the ID with the first character as 1, the result does not print on the txt.NewCar.Text. Another question is, how do I calculate the numbers of car sold? Any tips would be greatly appreciated. I am not sure if I am doing it right.

Comment: Instead of using `Substring()` for a single character you should use [**`Chars`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, you are using the [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) function incorrectly, by passing only one value, you are instructing it to give you the string from that point to the end. What you should be doing is:

```
strInput.Substring(0, 1) ' Get the first character
```

and

```
 strInput.Substring(3, 1) ' Get the fourth character
```

For the second problem, both `intFullTime` and `intPartTime` are local variables, they are created and initialised to 0 each time the button is clicked. You should move those two variables to be member variables of your class and then the totals should accumulate each time the button is clicked and the values parsed/processed.

Comment: I figured it out for the most part. Thank you for your helpful tips! Everything is accumulating except the Full-Time and Part-Time. The number stays the same or changes when i change the number of cars sold. but does not add up. Any tips?

Comment: Did you **move** the `intFullTime` and `intPartTime` variables to be member variables of the form/class? If you created new variables and left the old ones in the Click event, it won't work as you want it to

Comment: It is working now! Thank you for you time! For some reason Visual Studio was having a malfunction. But everything works! Thank you very much again!